# C++11 values of non-fixed enumeration?

Tags: c++, c++11

In C++11 7.2.7 it says:

> For an enumeration [with a non-fixed underlying type] where `e_min` is the smallest enumerator and `e_max` is the largest, the values of the enumeration are the values in the range `b_min` to `b_max` defined as follows... [snip]

I don't understand what it is defining here.  How are the range of possible values [`b_min`, `b_max`] distinct from the range of the enumerators [`e_min`, `e_max`] ?

Perhaps an example could help of a specific enumeration definition and the calculation of `e_min`, `e_max`, `b_min` and `b_max`?

Comment: Think about bits. Example: If you have `enum Mask { flag_A = 1<<0, flag_B = 1<<1 };` then "`e_min`" is `flag_A` i.e. "`0b01`" (in base 2) i.e. `1`, and "`e_max`" is `flag_B` i.e. "`0b10`" i.e. `2`, and this enum can be represented using 2 bits and is unsigned (never negative). Then "`b_min`" is "`0b00`" i.e. `0` and "`b_max`" is "`0b11`" i.e. `3`, so that you can use `Mask(0)` or `Mask(flag_A|flag_B)` and write tests like `if (m & flag_A) ...`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++ you can use enums as bit-masks.

For example:

```
enum Flag {
    Read = 1 << 0,
    Write = 1 << 1,
    WithSugar = 1 << 2
};
```

Then you can say: `Flag f = Read | Write | WithSugar;` and `f`'s value is perfectly defined: `assert(f == 7);`!

It's inherited from C...

In our case, the rules says that `Flag` should be able to represent any value from `0` (enums are positive unless a negative enumerator exist) to `7`.

The value `7` is determined by taking the largest enumerator (`WithSguar`: 4) and looking for `k` such that `2^(k-1) <= 4 < 2^k - 1`. The maximum representable value is then `2^k-1`. It makes sense if you consider the bitwise representation of the value in 2-complement: `4` is `100` so you can fill the `00` with `1` without taking more space, giving `111` as the maximum value, which happens to be `7`.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize there was actual language support for using enumerations as bit masks.  The definition makes sense now.